# HTML5 CSS3 Logo and NavBar Responsive (NO BOOTSTRAP!!)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the logo to be responsive and keep the same proportions on a small and large screen. However the logo is too large at full resolution on a laptop but is close to the correct size on a smaller screen. Any help on how to fix the image size is appreciated. Oh, and please don't tell me to use bootstrap or any frameworks!

[Click here for cookies!](https://jsfiddle.net/kaaxdgb8/)

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px blue solid;
}
#logo {
  display: block;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  border-style: 2px green solid;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>



  Archery Club</title>

<body>

  <!--Defines a header for a document or a section-->
  <header>
  </header>

  <!--Defines a container for navigation links-->
  <nav>
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <img id="logo" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/durjwdzkx/image/upload/v1480113900/IMG001_kwt1of.png" />
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Location</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Competitions</a>
      </li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>


  <!-- Defines a footer for a document or a section-->
  <footer>
    Site by: Me &copy; 2016
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: maybe the logo dimensions are too big to start with?

Comment: @AlekseiMaide what dimensions are logo sizes typically?

Comment: images on the web should not be larger than they need to be :) bandwidth/load time etc. the size of your image should be as big as is neccesary to display it at its largest intended resolution without sacrificing quality.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide ok, the image i have currently is 483px by 252px with a size of 22.1KB. If thats too large for a logo how can I tell in the future?

Comment: the resolution is most likely too large, but the size is ok :) how to tell... well width of a smartphone is around 320px (more or less) and a image of 483px in width is 1,5 times that, common sense will help :) but you could also scale the image with css width, height (wrap inside of a html element and add a class to select)

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using for do responsive design without any lib or framework It's flexbox! It's supported by the browsers natively.. It has some years already.. Here you have the [compatibility list](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

And here you have an amazing guide about how it works.. You should give it a try:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that the image is obviously too large I would first resize the image in any image editing software

```
<img id="logo" src="">
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
width: %; //whatever percentage you find most appropriate 
}
```

but keep in mind that the width is dependant on the parent container (100% is the width of the parent).

In your case the parent is "ul" which takes up 100% of the width and therefore the logo takes up 35% of the width.